# How to get variable "SafeFileNames" from another method?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get variable "SafeFileNames" from another method?
In button 1 I have OpenFileDialog and in button 2 I want to get all file names.

I use loop:

```
foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames)
```

and in Public Partial Class Form I have:
      `public string[] fileName { get; private set; }`

but it doesn't work. I could create new array and fill in first method but I'm searching another better solution.

## CODE:

I have something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string[] fileName { get; private set; }
    int numberOfFiles { get; set; }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;

        openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;

        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
        openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = false;
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        textBox1.Text = "";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            int number = 0;
            foreach (string fileName in openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames)
            {
            }
        }
        }
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    HERE - I want to know string from openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames
    }
```

Now `string[] fileName` is null.

Comment: You want to get filenames in the same folder? Why don't u use the OpenFolderDialog?

Comment: `openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;` specific files not the whole folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling the second method from the first method, you could just pass the string array to the second method. Else, you can use a private field in your class to reference the array and use in your second method.

**Edit**: You can edit your code as follows :

```
public Form1()
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
}
public string[] fileNames { get; private set; }
int numberOfFiles { get; set; }

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your openFileDialog1 initialisation and other stuff here
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileNames = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
        numberOfFiles = fileName.Length;
    }
}
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
    {
        //You can access the name of each file using fileName now
    }
}
```

I think you are having some confusions with the iterating variable in the foreach loop. That variable exists only inside the loop and it is assigned a new value on each iteration.

Comment: I edited my answer. Does it answer your question now?
Also, please delete your answer and add it to the question as it is a part of the question.